# struct pointer manipulation

Tags: c, struct

The Code used

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct st
{
 char a;
 short c;
 int b;
};

struct st s1;
int main()
{
        printf("%p %p \n",(&s1.b)-1, &s1);
}
```

If I print the address of `&s1.b` it prints `0x804a01c` and `&s1.b-2` prints `0x804a018` 
why it is printing same address `0x804a01c` if i select `&s1.b-1` ?

Comment: Structure padding is implementation defined.

Comment: @Prasoon: it's nothing to do with structure padding: `&s1.b` is an `int*`, and the padding in the structure has no effect on how pointer arithmetic works with an `int*`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Exactly. Plus one on your comment.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, you are correct.Probably I was thinking something else.

Comment: I am using gcc in ubuntu

Comment: @C Learner: Can you please post a minimum compilable code that shows your problem, or post the output of the program I posted below.

Comment: @C Learner: The answer to your question is: it doesn't. It doesn't print the same address for `&s.b - 1`. You either a) must have confused the results of different tests, or b) doing something completely different from what you described in your question.

Comment: Based on your code, I think that you meant "If I print the address of `&s1` it prints `0x804a01c` and `&s1.b-2` prints `0x804a018` why it is printing same address `0x804a01c` if i select `&s1.b-1`?" Please see my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033915/struct-pointer-manipulation/2037610#2037610) below.

Comment: Your question is wrong.  `&s1.b-1` and `&s1.b` don't print the same value in your case, `&s1.b-1` and `&s1` do.  This just happens to be true on your machine.  You can't rely on this behavior.  The answer is structure padding.  You could have saved everyone a lot of grief if you had posted your code to begin with.

Comment: @Alok: Completely agree. Based on his code he definitely meant to ask why `&s1` and `&s1.b - 1` are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting your code. Now I see the issue. It is because of padding. To wit:

```
printf("sizeof(char): %d\n", sizeof(char));
printf("sizeof(short): %d\n", sizeof(short));
printf("sizeof(int): %d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("sizeof(struct st): %d\n", sizeof(struct st));
```

On my machine this prints

```
1
2
4
8
```

You might think, shouldn't `sizeof(struct st)` be `1 + 2 + 4 = 7`? That's certainly a reasonable thought but because of [alignment issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) there is padding between `a` and `c`. Therefore, in memory, the struct looks like the following (relative to the first byte of the struct):

```
0x00000000: char                 a
0x00000001: padding
0x00000002: first byte of short  c
0x00000003: second byte of short c
0x00000004: first byte of int    b
0x00000005: second byte of int   b
0x00000006: third byte of int    b
0x00000007: fourth byte of int   b
```

Consequently (relative to `&s1`):

```
&s1.b - 1 is ((long)&s1.b) - sizeof(int) = 4 - 4 = 0 = &s1
```

This is why both `&s1` and `&s1.b - 1` will print the same address. In particular if

```
&s1 = 0x804a01c
```

then

```
&s1.b = 0x804a01c + 0x00000004 = 0x804a020
```

and

```
&s1.b - 1 = 0x804a020 - 0x00000004 = 0x804a01c
```

and

```
&s1.b - 2 = 0x804a020 - 0x00000008 = 0x804a018
```

Note, finally, that this is implementation-specific behavior. This is not portable!

Answer (score 7):

There's probably something wrong with your printing code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct st
{
 char a;
 short c;
 int b;
};

struct st s1;

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(&s1.b));
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(&s1.b - 1));
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(&s1.b - 2));
}
```

Output:

```
0x403024
0x403020
0x40301c
```

Comment: declare the struct s1 as global

Comment: @C Learner: Declaring `s1` as global will not change the behavior (pointer arithmetic is defined very clearly and there is no part of the specification that allows implemenation-specific details to be intervening here).

Comment: @C Learner: Why would that matter?

Comment: It is behaving differently if i change this into local.. I am using gcc

Comment: What do you mean it's behaving differently? It prints different addresses (that's fine) or it exhibits the mysterious behavior you were describing in your OP?

Comment: Maybe he is on a 64-bit cpu, then using %x is wrong. The right choice is %p.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're printing it wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct st
{
   char a;
   short c;
   int b;
};
struct st s;

int main(void)
{
    printf("s: %p\n", (void *)&s);
    printf("s.a: %p\n", (void *)&s.a);
    printf("s.b: %p\n", (void *)&s.b);
    printf("s.b-1: %p\n", (void *)(&s.b-1));
    printf("s.b-2: %p\n", (void *)(&s.b-2));
    return 0;
}
```

Prints for me:

```
s: 0x100001068
s.a: 0x100001068
s.b: 0x10000106c
s.b-1: 0x100001068
s.b-2: 0x100001064
```

Things to note:

- Pointer to struct == pointer to struct's first element (guaranteed by the C standard),
- I am printing the pointers with `"%p"` format string.  `"%p"` needs `void *`, and since `printf` is a variadic function, I need to cast the arguments to `printf` to `void *` in this case.

What does the above program print for you?

*Edit*: based upon the actual code posted for printing that you posted later: you are not getting the same value for `&s1.b` and `&s1.b-1`.  You are getting the same value for `&s1.b-1` and `&s1`.  The answer to that is: *this happens because of chance*.  In your case, there is struct padding, and `sizeof(short)+sizeof(char)` happens to be ≤ `sizeof(int)`.  If you were on a machine where any of those assumptions were invalid, you wouldn't see that behavior.  I am sure if you changed `char` or `short` to `int` in your code, `&s1.b-1` would *not* equal `&s1`, when printed.

Finally, you should cast pointers to `void *` before printing:

```
printf("%p %p \n",(void *)((&s1.b)-1), (void *)&s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the address of s1.b is 0x804a01c, then &s1.b-2 should be 0x804a014 (assuming that int is 4 bytes), not 0x804a018. Perhaps you made a mistake when you reported the address?

Comment: You mean 4 bytes, not 32 bit :-).  4 bytes == 32 bit iff `CHAR_BIT == 8`.